# How do I use \Drupal methods in a class?

Tags: 9

I was out of Drupal for a few years, and PHP a couple years, due to having several years of jobs that didn't use Drupal between two that did. And I'm noticing a lot of functions that were reliable are now gone.

The particular case I am currently looking at is `variable_get()` occurrences replaced by `\Drupal::state()->get()`.

However, I tried using it, and it's far from a drop-in replacement. In a class in a module I was working on, I tried changing `$lm = variable_get('user_import_line_max');` to `$line_max = \Drupal::state()->get('user_import_line_max');` but this complained that it can't be used inside a class (despite the fact the function could).

How do I use `\Drupal` methods in a class?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This site is set up for answering one question at a time.

Comment: What does "this complained that it can't be used inside a class" mean, technically? Are you talking about the documentation which suggests it is an unsustainable practice, or, some kind of an error message?

Comment: @cilefen I've already started refactoring my code so I don't get the error anymore, but it was specifically an error when I first tried it, along the lines of "\Drupal::state()->get() cannot be used inside of a class".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\Drupal::state()` is a static helper function intended for use *in procedural code*. It returns the singleton "State" object (called a "service") from the [service container](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/container/10). `\Drupal::state()->get()` is a chained method call that then calls the `get` method on the state service.

In object-oriented code the advice is to use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) patterns, the most common type of which is [constructor injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Constructor_injection), to obtain service container objects. A strong argument for using dependency injection is that it facilitates unit testing your classes. The Drupal API documentation I linked to in the above paragraph explains using the service container in some detail.

As a sample you could look at core's [*DbUpdateController.php*](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/10.0.7/core/modules/system/src/Controller/DbUpdateController.php). There you can see how the State service is first injected:

- [`protected $state;`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/10.0.7/core/modules/system/src/Controller/DbUpdateController.php#L44)
- [`$this->state = $state;`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/10.0.7/core/modules/system/src/Controller/DbUpdateController.php#L105)
- [`$container->get('state'),`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/10.0.7/core/modules/system/src/Controller/DbUpdateController.php#L120)

And how it later is used inside the controller:

- [`$maintenance_mode = $this->state->get('system.maintenance_mode', FALSE);`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/10.0.7/core/modules/system/src/Controller/DbUpdateController.php#L583)
- [`$this->state->set('system.maintenance_mode', TRUE);`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/10.0.7/core/modules/system/src/Controller/DbUpdateController.php#L590)

Comment: The added sample is a more complex DI pattern using the factory method create(). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern. In Drupal this is only necessary for controllers or plugins, which are not registered as service in the container.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Cliefen's very good answer, you can view the documentation for the `\Drupal` class here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/class/Drupal/10

It provides a list of all functions that can be called statically off the class.

Comment: One thing I'm still trying to figure out is what that leading slash does in \Drupal, as I haven't really seen that before. Is it literally just part of the name, like the dollar sign in JQuery (which I loath due to it interfering with me writing PHP code) or is it actually doing something?

Comment: This is about namespaces. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php. `\Drupal` is a fully-qualified class name while `Drupal` is not. The latter works only if you add `use Drupal;` to a class or in procedural code.

Comment: The back slash at the start indicates that the class is in the global namespace. So `\Drupal` is in the global namespace. An example module for example could declare it's own class named `Drupal` in a separate namespace, such as `\Drupal\example\Drupal`, and these would not conflict, as they are in different namespaces.

Comment: Ah, so that's why I never came across it before, as I tend to avoid coding with globals and Drupal didn't use to use it. Thanks for the clarification!